# Ошибка в телеграм бот API, ошибка с keyboard, NameError: name 'types' is not defined?

Tags: python, telegram

Вот код

```
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['choice'])
def inline(message):
    key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    but_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Альфредо", callback_data="Альфредо")
    but_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Челентано", callback_data="Челентано")
    key.add(but_1, but_2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Кто же твой кумир?", reply_markup=key)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def inlin(c):
    if c.data == 'Альфредо':
    bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'Да')
    if c.data == 'Челентано':
    bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'Нет')
```

Выводит ошибку:

```
NameError: name 'types' is not defined
```

Помогите с решением проблемы

Comment: Переменная `types` не определена. Скорее всего, Вы забыли импортировать её из какого-то модуля.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего вы забыли сделать импорт
`from telebot import types`